# How to parse multiple lines from a .txt file and put them in a single line using batch script

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop

I have a .txt file which contains a list of, let's say, numbers, one on each line.
I want to parse that .txt file and put all those numbers in a single line, separated by a space. What i tried so far, was just to see if i can parse the lines from a text, but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried this command:

```
C:\Users\Adi>for /F "tokens=*" %A in ("file.txt") do (set line=%G echo !line!)
```

but as result i get just:

```
C:\Users\Adi>(set line=file.txt echo !line!)
```

Content of my .txt file:

> ```
> 685576
> 685569
> 685564
> 685265
> 685229
> 685222
> 685121
> 684189
> 683905
> 681508
> 681321
> 680799
> 680436
> 679650
> 679424
> ```

I would like to have those all in a single line, separated by a space. Can you please tell me whee i go wrong?
Thank you!

To mention that my .txt has more that 100 lines. Not sure if this may impact in some way!
Thank you!

Adi C

Comment: What you've specified in your title and your tag is `batch file`, what you've posted is code for `cmd.exe`, which is it you're wanting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full batch file to hopefully achieve what you want:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("myFiles.txt") Do @Call Set "line=%%line%% %%A"
@Echo(%line:~1%&@Pause
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct but I don't get why you remove the first character.

Comment: Because the first character is a not requested single space character! _(each instance of `%%A` is being prepended with that space character so the final string will have one at the beginning)_.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of appending multiple lines of a text file to a single one is to append them in a variable and to output its content at once, as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46446734) -- although I would prefer [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) over `call` due to better performance and safety against special characters:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dpn0.txt"    & rem // (path of source file)
set "_TARGET=%~dp0line.txt" & rem // (path of target file)
set "_SEPCHR= "             & rem // (separator character)

rem // Initialise buffers:
set "COLL=" & set "SEP="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_SOURCE%") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem /* Use delayed expansion to append lint to buffer in order to avoid
    rem    trouble with special characters; use a `for /F` loop to transport
    rem    the buffer beyond the `endlocal` barrier: */
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%K in ("!COLL!!SEP!!LINE!") do (
        endlocal & set "COLL=%%K"
    )
    rem // Apply separator character only after the first line:
    set "SEP=%_SEPCHR%"
)
rem // Write collected buffer data into target file:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "!_TARGET!" echo(!COLL!
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

However, the above approach fails if the total length of the build output line exceeds about 8190 bytes or characters.

Here is an improved version, which does not limit the length of the output line; the line lengths of the input file is still limited to about 8190 bytes/characters though:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dpn0.txt"    & rem // (path of source file)
set "_TARGET=%~dp0line.txt" & rem // (path of target file)
set "_TMPLIN=%~dp0line.tmp" & rem // (path of temporary file)
set "_SEPCHR= "             & rem // (separator character)

rem // Store an EOF (end-of-file) character in a variable:
for /F %%K in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo/0x1A"') do set "EOF=%%K"
rem // Ensure the target file to exist and to be empty:
> "%_TARGET%" rem/
rem // Read source file line by line:
set "FIRST=#"
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_SOURCE%") do (
    rem // Write current line into temporary file with an EOF character appended:
    > "%_TMPLIN%" (
        if defined FIRST (
            rem // Do not prepend a separator character to first line:
            echo(%%L%EOF%
            set "FIRST="
        ) else (
            rem // Do prepend a separator character to every other line:
            echo(%_SEPCHR%%%L%EOF%
        )
    )
    rem /* Append content of temporary file to target file; since EOF characters and
    rem    everything behind are ignored in text mode (`/A`), also the line-breaks
    rem    introduced by `echo` are not included in the output; to avoid a final EOF
    rem    character to be appended, the target file must be declared binary (`/B`): */
    > nul copy /A "%_TARGET%" + "%_TMPLIN%" "%_TARGET%" /B
)
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMPLIN%"

endlocal
exit /B
```